# How to write testcase in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, grails-test

> - I am newbie in Rails test. so how can I start my testing.
> - Anyone Knows better tutorial for Rails testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rails built in library to write test cases. After getting some familiarity with it you can proceed with Rspec and learn it with various ebook book.

You can follow following tutorial for rspec 
[tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rspec/index.htm)